# Good book on (Quantum) Complexity and Computability Theories to start learning the theorem $MIP^* = RE$ as an operator algebraist

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing, interactive-proof-systems, recursively-enumerable

I am looking for some greatest references that could help me understand the theorem $MIP^* = RE$  ([$MIP*=RE$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04383)) step by step. The paper ([The Connes Embedding Problem: A guided tour](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.12682v1)) covers various topics related to this problem, but it is very brief. As a student with bacgrouds on operator algebras (von Neumann algebras, C*-algebras), free probability and random matrices) and with basic knowledge on quantum mechanics, I am looking for documents on quantum complexity theory that align with my intellectual background. What book should I read to fully grasp a concept before moving on to another?